# Drawing controls with GDI on Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, mobile, textbox, gdi

I need to draw a textbox in a Compact Framework app, but using directly a Graphics object.

I've found the Control.DrawToBitmap method, which I could use for drawing with GDI, but it's not available on Compact Framework.

Any hints?

Comment: Drawing a textbox in another application? Else is direct drawing on the Graphics not an option?

Comment: I'm not using the standard WinForms controls, but other library of GDI based controls. I need to create my own TextBox from scratch (time-constraints don't let me do this), or being able of drawing a WinForms TextBox with GDI. 

I have not found how to direct draw on Graphics on CF.

Answer (score 1):

Control.DrawToBitmap() is implemented by sending WM_PRINT to the control to let it draw itself in a memory device context.  If you are using non-standard controls, the odds are great that the programmer did not implement this message.  I don't think it is implemented by the standard Windows Mobile controls either.

Your only other recourse then is to copy the pixels off the screen.  Graphics.CopyFromScreen() is a no-go, you'll have to P/Invoke the BitBlt() API function.  Possibly useful sample code is available in [this thread.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/474450b9-e260-4369-9efb-0d57a5b2e06d) and at pinvoke.net

Comment: I did the BitBit p/Invoke, but got a black image (I think that's because of the controls not being visible in any form). If I use visible controls it works. Thanks anyway :(

Comment: The problem is that in Windows Mobile I can only have an active screen, so puting the StartLocation out of the bounds of it it's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Well typically you just inherit from : Control, override OnPaint and use the graphics object provided by the arguments. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: With this I can draw text, lines, polygons, bitmaps, etc. But how I can get the "image" from a textbox that is not in any control?

Comment: Eh? You want to get the image that is drawn by the control? You cannot get this, unless you implement the control yourself and expose it via a property. You could do this by drawing the control on a graphics object created by Graphics.FromImage() then expose that image via a property before finally drawing the control by using Graphics.DrawImage on the "main" graphics object in the event args. You would have to re-implement every single control this way though so it would be a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this would work.... but technically you could use reflection to call into the control's OnPaint method and pass in your own graphics object (Graphics.FromImage) in a new set of PaintEventArgs.

It's ugly as hell..... but it *might* work.